# focus event not triggered when calling window.focus()

Tags: javascript, events

I call `window.blur()` and with a timeout I later call `window.focus()`, but this does not seem to trigger the `window.onfocus` event. Is that intentional?

```
                window.addEventListener("focus", (event) => console.warn(event));
                window.blur();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.focus();
                }, 1000);
```

Comment: according to the *[window.focus() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) - Makes a request to bring the window to the front. It may fail due to user settings and the window isn't guaranteed to be frontmost before this method returns.)* - it may also be that `window.blur()` does nothing at all - try adding a blur event handler to see if it does anything

Answer (score 1):

yes this is intentional behavior. These events in your example are meant for user-based interaction. But here you're trying to achieve this programmatically. Thus, once your window.blur() is executed after that window.focus event is not triggered by timeout. If you are trying to check when window is focused after getting blur() then you need to do a work around like setting a flag or something.